# Correction for garage door opener that leaks current to bulb?

Tags: lighting, garage-door-opener

I've got an Alister Access 3000 garage door opener.  The normal light bulb is a standard rough service 60 watt incandescent.  It has the unfortunate side effect of melting the plastic lens cover over time.  So, this time when I ordered a new lens cover I also ordered a Genie garage door opener LED bulb as that won't be so hot.

However, after installation and about 10 seconds after plugging the door opener back into the power the LED starts to glow softly.  It goes full brightness when it should, but instead of "off" it always glows slightly.  Presumably this door opener was not designed with such a sensitive light bulb in mind.  Any easy modifications to keep it from glowing?  Does not seem to be a huge problem (and honestly it makes for a nice night light when coming in the ped door in the evening), but I feel like I should at least attempt to correct it...

Comment: What causes the light to turn on or off normally? Is it always a manual hard wall switch, does the opener automatically turn it on/off, lighted switch, dimmer, motion sensor anything like that?

Comment: @Harper The opener does it automatically

Comment: Based on which conditions? For instance does it have a motion sensor?  Timer?

Comment: The light is probably controlled by an scr this is an electronic switch that uses a gate voltage to turn on. The very small amount of current used with this kind of switch is enough to light an led light, the only way I know of would requiring adding additional electronics and then the opener would not be ul listed.

Comment: Different bulbs may have different outcomes as well.  I’ve learned that name brand bulbs such as GE, Phillips, Sylvania, etc don’t ghost like cheaply made bulbs.  If you like it, as a night light, why not just leave it?  Changing the bulb won’t stop the current leakage, it simply has a higher threshold to glow.

Comment: How about those resistor units that who, Leviton I think makes? You wire them in parallel with the lamp.

Comment: @Harper It's timer based.  Goes on when the door starts in motion, shuts off probably around 5 minutes later.  Doesn't trigger on walking through the eyes like other ones do that I'm familiar with.  Maybe I'll just leave it alone and enjoy the nightlight like Tyson says.  I added some lightweight insulation to the garage door windows to avoid contributing to light pollution due to the glow.